# Rest Framework incorrect validation on update using SlugRelatedField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have successfully used `SlugRelatedField` to validate relationship with other model in `create`. However when I `use update`, it does not validate correctly.

Suppose I have:

```
#models.py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} XL".format(self.name)

class Query(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    ...

#serializers.py
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

class QuerySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = serializers.SLugRelatedField(slug_field='name', queryset=Product.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Query
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        product = validated_data.pop('product').name
        ...

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.product = validated_data.get('product', instance.product)
        ...
```

When I POST, it gets successful:

```
{
    "name": "Query 1",
    "product": "Pants",
    ...
}
```

But when I PATCH, it gets problem and got a response error. I know the `__str__` in the model complicates things. However I want to solve it without removing it.

```
{
    ...
    "product": "Shirt",
    ...
}
```

Response Error:

```
{'product': ['Object with name=Shirt XL does not exist.']}
```

How can I catch validation on update? I tried adding `validate` to print the data. But why is not printing when updating?

```
def validate(self, data):
    print(data)    # Does not print on update
    return data
```

Is there also a way to change it before `update` to make `product = product.name` like I did in `create`?

Answer (score 0):

usually the slug field must be unique , so set a flag `unique=True`
,
When using `SlugRelatedField` as a read-write field, you will normally want to ensure that the slug field corresponds to a model field with `unique=True` either must be some sort of `pk` or `uuid` object.

Also you can generate your  own slug and use it

```
def generate_slug(n=7):
    return ''.join(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(n))
```